# Sorting variables after importing Excel information into Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, sorting, variables

Hello I'm learning how to use Matlab for the first time and I am stuck on an assignment. Its a two part assignment the first one is to write an Matlab script and have it output an Excel file which I have done.

```
M = {'City' 'Population'; 'Chandler' 249146; 'Gilbert' 229972; 
'Glendale' 234632; 'Mesa' 457587; 'Peoria' 162592; 
'Phoenix' 1513367; 'Scottsdale' 226918; 'Surprise' 123546;
'Tempe' 168228; 'Tucson' 526116};

M = xlswrite('largest_cities_in_arizona.xls',M)
```

The second part is to create a Matlab script that reads the Excel file, creates two variables named city_population and city_name and then sorts both in descending order based upon the population. I have most of this figured out.

```
[A, B] = xlsread('largest_cities_in_arizona.xls', 1, 'A2:B11');

city_population = sort(A, 'descend');

city_name = sort(B);
```

The problem I am having is trying to sort the city_name by the city_population. When importing the data Matlab treats city_name as a 10x1 cell and city_population as a matrix, and gives me dimension errors if I try to sort B based upon city_population. Is there some other way to do this? Any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[city_population, index] = sort(A, 'descend');
city_name = B(index);
```

The key is to use the second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) as an index which you apply to the other array to get the same order.

In your example, this gives

```
>> city_population
city_population =
     1513367
      526116
      457587
      249146
      234632
      229972
      226918
      168228
      162592
      123546

>> city_name
city_name = 
    'Phoenix'
    'Tucson'
    'Mesa'
    'Chandler'
    'Glendale'
    'Gilbert'
    'Scottsdale'
    'Tempe'
    'Peoria'
    'Surprise'
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. I had no idea about the index ability.

Comment: Many Matlab functions have optional outputs which give you additional information. About indexing in general: see for example [this](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).